# Customize cell colour in a report

Tags: .net, reporting-services

As the title indicates i want to customize cells colours in a report (I'm working on a reports application)
i.e: my report contains a table that is filled with integers from 1 to 4.

```
1--> red
2--> green
. 
. 
.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the background color or the font color property for the field (whichever one you are wanting to color). Then go to expression. In the expression do something similar to this:

```
=Switch(Fields!Field.Value = 1, "Red" , Fields!Field.Value = 2, "Green", Fields!Field.Value =  3, "Black")
```